# Expressjs - end request with no redirect/render

Tags: node.js, express

Right now on my website I have a browse page that has a search form. When you view results, there is an option along each row of the table to add ownership of the item. Currently when you click the ownership button, the request looks like:

```
app.get('/addown/:id', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    req.user.owneditems.addToSet(req.params.id);
    req.user.save();
    res.redirect('/browse');
});
```

Instead of redirecting back to the main /browse page, I'd like the user to stay on the current page so they can continue viewing whatever search parameters they chose. Is there any way if the request is successful I say to end it and not leave/change the page at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For that to happen you need to use some AJAX based communication with the server.
In you example, I assume the code is from the web page server side call, hence you directed the browser already to /addown/:id hence you need to send a response (aka page content) or a redirect.

To accomplish what you want you need to change the web page implementation. You do NOT leave or navigate from the page, when you click on each row you make an AJAX call to the same route and return simply 200 OK if successful. That way you "slide" into single page application concept.

Look into angular.js or knockout.js to help you with that unless you want to code that yourself in the table and put a function call on click event on each row.